# Powershell Script to find the file from multiple servers and export to Excel

Tags: powershell

So far I have created a PowerShell script to find the specific files from multiple servers and dump the output to excel file.

For some reason my script only dumps the output for 1 server (last one to the list) out of 50. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
$server = get-content "C:\temp\servers.txt"
Foreach ($srv in $server) 
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$srv\d$\temp\" -include "java_pid*" -Recurse -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | export-csv c:\temp\results.csv
}
```

When run the script it will go thru all the servers and dump the export to excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -Append tag  this will append each of the server results pipeline into one long results.csv. Right now you are overwriting the output csv for each server.

```
$server = get-content "C:\temp\servers.txt" Foreach ($srv in $server) { Get-ChildItem -Path "\$srv\d$\temp\" -include "java_pid*" -Recurse -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | export-csv c:\temp\results.csv -Append}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked well.. now I'd like to delete the files which found from csv file. Is there a simple way to delete? REMOVE-Item "\\$servername\d$\temp\java_bin*.hprof" -Recurse

Comment: I was able to find out .. Thank you for your help!!